# Unity3d why doesn't changing an object's localposition by 1 correspond to moving one grid division?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I opened the example standard assets project after reading about half the unity documentation to try to get a feel for things as I read through the documentation.

However, I'm very confused about positioning things in unity.

I am looking at the 2d character scene in the project, and when i move the platforms' Transform components' Local position property by 1, it doesn't seem to move one unit on the grid that unity displays. What determines unity's grid size?

Platform 04x01 is located at position x = 45 y = 7.5002 z = 0 in the example project in scene 2dplatformer.

in the screenshot here:

http://postimg.org/image/inhbr3b47/

it is located within a blue grid.

When i change x to 46, I expect the platform to move over by 1 according to the grid.

Instead it looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/4ps2rcvgv/

Why could this occur?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your images, the problem that is occuring is that you are in debugging mode. To exit debugging mode do the following:
In the inspector, in the top right corner you will see a tiny drop down menu next to a lock. Click the dropdown menu and select normal. Now the Transform will have Position, Rotation, and Scale, rather than local versions of these.
Now in Normal mode, the grid squares will be ten by ten unit squares. When I say unit, I am refering to the units used in the scale in Transform.
To put this into perspective, say I make a square and unity and set its scale values all to 10, by doing this our cube will now have a base that is 10 by 10 units in size and will therefore take up the entire grid scale.
Now instead say I dont change the scale, and keep it at unity's default values of 1. We now have a cube with a base that is 1 by 1 units in size. So in order to move it from one side of the grid square to the other, we must move the object by 10 units in the x or y transform.
So in short, to fix your problem, follow my steps to exit debugging mode, and from here keep in mind that the grid in unity is composed of 10 by 10 unity squares. However, if in your game you want to make your objects locked in a grid, you will need to set this up on your own as unity's grid view is only meant for reference and has no functionality as for grid locking objects.

Comment: this is so confusing. i guess i need to explain my question better then. will rewrite in a couple min

Comment: All I am saying is the grid squares are 10 units by 10 units. So if your object starts on the very edge of a grid square, then if you move it 10 units to the right, then it would end up on the edge of that grid square.

Comment: But if you look at the example images i posted, there is a giant square that is divided into 16 squares and moving x by 2.5 moves it one giant square to the right. That's why i'm wondering if there is some option to change the division (since it seems to be 2.5/4 units per small square).

if not, i'm wondering if it is somehow based off of the sprite renderer being displayed or something else.

Comment: Thank you for posting the pics, Try seeing if this new solution makes any sense.

Comment: ah i have to go will look at it in an hour.. looks good though. thanks a lot

Comment: ok it wasn't that, but i think i figured it out. it seems like the lines that i thought were part of unity are part of some background. thanks anyway